# Vectorize for-loop - need to average slices of varying size

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, vectorization

I am trying to average subword embeddings to form a word-level representation. Each word has a corresponding start and end index, indicating which subwords make up that word.

**`sequence_output`** is a tensor of B * 3 * 2, where 3 is the max sequence length, and 2 is the number of features.

**`all_token_mapping`** is a tensor of B * 3 * 2, which contains a start and end index.

**`initial_reps`** is a tensor of num_nodes * 2, num_nodes is the sum of all the number of words (not subwords) in the different samples.

```
sequence_output = torch.arange(2*3*2).float().reshape(2, 3, 2)
tensor([[[ 0.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  3.],
         [ 4.,  5.]],

        [[ 6.,  7.],
         [ 8.,  9.],
         [10., 11.]]])
```

```
all_token_mapping = torch.tensor([[[0,0],[1,2],[-1,-1]], [[0,2],[-1,-1],[-1,-1]]])
tensor([[[ 0,  0],
         [ 1,  2],
         [-1, -1]],

        [[ 0,  2],
         [-1, -1],
         [-1, -1]]])
```

```
num_nodes = 0
for sample in all_token_mapping:
  for mapping in sample:
    if mapping[0] != -1:
      num_nodes += 1
3
```

```
initial_reps = torch.empty((num_nodes, 2), dtype=torch.float32)
current_idx = 0
for i, feature_tokens_mapping in enumerate(all_token_mapping):
    for j, token_mapping in enumerate(feature_tokens_mapping):
        if token_mapping[0] == -1: # reached the end for this particular sequence
            break
        initial_reps[current_idx] = torch.mean(sequence_output[i][token_mapping[0]:token_mapping[-1] + 1], 0, keepdim=True)                                           
        current_idx += 1
initial_reps
tensor([[0., 1.],
        [3., 4.],
        [8., 9.]])
```

In the example above, initial_reps[0] will be the mean of sequence_output[0][0:1], initial_reps[1] will be the mean of sequence_output[0][1:3], and initial_reps[2] will be the mean of sequence_output[1][0:3].

My current code will create an empty tensor of length num_nodes, and a for loop will calculate the values at each index, by checking token_mapping[0] and token_mapping[1] for the correct slice of sequence_output to average.

Is there a way to vectorize this code?

In addition, I have a list that holds the number of words for each sample. i.e. the sum of all the elements in the list == num_nodes

Comment: helping you is difficult without having a minimal reproducible example that includes an example for an input and expected output:  
  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: hi, sorry about that..
i've simplified the example and added input and expected output. could you take another look? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way with the help of someone over at https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/vectorize-for-loop-need-to-average-slices-of-varying-size/122618/2

```
initial_reps_list = []
for i, sample_output in enumerate(sequence_output):
    token_mapping = all_token_mapping[i]
    token_mapping = token_mapping[token_mapping != -1]
    non_padded_outputs = sample_output[:num_bert_tokens[i]]
    initial_reps_list.append(torch_scatter.segment_coo(non_padded_outputs, token_mapping, reduce="mean"))

initial_reps = torch.cat(initial_reps_list)
```

token_mapping is a list of indices in ascending order up to the max sequence length, padded with -1. I loop through the batch, for each sample, I get the token mapping, and only keep the non-negative indices.

num_bert_tokens is a list that holds, for each sample, the number of tokens (no padding). I get the non-padded outputs, use segment_coo to reduce them according to the token_mapping, and append them all to a list.

After the loop, I concatenate all the tensors in the list together.

The method segment_coo reduces all values from the src tensor into out at the indices specified in the index tensor along the last dimension of index. More details can be found at: https://pytorch-scatter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/segment_coo.html

Runs much faster now!

Answer (score 0):

I would do smth like what I show in the following code. the case is very much simplified so I can show you an example of an input and output. but the concept is scalable to any array size or dimension. I changed the '768' to the variable 'num_features' which I set to 5. and reduced the number of source nodes from 384 to 4.

import torch

```
B = 3
num_nodes0 = 4
num_nodes = 3
num_features = 5

sequence_output = torch.arange(B * num_nodes0 * num_features).float()
sequence_output = sequence_output.reshape(B, num_nodes0, num_features)

all_token_mapping = torch.randint(0, num_nodes0, (B, num_nodes))

idx0 = torch.arange(B).reshape(-1, 1).repeat(1, num_nodes).flatten().long()
idx1 = all_token_mapping.flatten().long()
initial_reps = sequence_output[idx0, idx1, :].reshape(B, num_nodes, num_features)
initial_reps = torch.mean(initial_reps, axis = 1)
```

output:

```
sequence_output = 
tensor([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
         [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.],
         [10., 11., 12., 13., 14.],
         [15., 16., 17., 18., 19.]],

        [[20., 21., 22., 23., 24.],
         [25., 26., 27., 28., 29.],
         [30., 31., 32., 33., 34.],
         [35., 36., 37., 38., 39.]],

        [[40., 41., 42., 43., 44.],
         [45., 46., 47., 48., 49.],
         [50., 51., 52., 53., 54.],
         [55., 56., 57., 58., 59.]]])
all_token_mapping = 
tensor([[0, 2, 1],
        [2, 3, 0],
        [2, 0, 0]])
initial_reps = 
tensor([[ 5.0000,  6.0000,  7.0000,  8.0000,  9.0000],
        [28.3333, 29.3333, 30.3333, 31.3333, 32.3333],
        [43.3333, 44.3333, 45.3333, 46.3333, 47.3333]])
```

Comment: Hi, sorry i don't understand your solution. Each index for initial_reps might average different number of things. I have rephrased the question a bit to make it clearer..could you take a look at it again?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem and found that cumulative sum could be used here:

```
>>> import torch
>>> hidden_states = torch.arange(4 * 5 * 2).reshape(4, 5, 2)
>>> target_segments_starts = torch.tensor([[0, 3, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 3, 0], [0, 1, 3]])
>>> target_segments_ends = torch.tensor([[2, 5, 0], [4, 0, 0], [3, 5, 0], [1, 3, 5]])
```

Note, I use a little another way to define start and end indexes. Also, I use 0 for padding as I can't pass -1 to `torch.gather`

```
>>> starts_reshaped = target_segments_starts.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1, hidden_states.shape[-1])  # just for torch.gather
>>> ends_reshaped = target_segments_ends.unsqueeze(-1).repeat(1, 1, hidden_states.shape[-1])  # just for torch.gather
>>> ends_reshaped_included = torch.where(ends_reshaped == 0, 0, ends_reshaped - 1)
>>> starts_reshaped_excluded = torch.where(starts_reshaped == 0, 0, starts_reshaped - 1)
>>> hidden_states_cumsum = hidden_states.cumsum(dim=1)
>>> starts_sums_excluded = torch.gather(hidden_states_cumsum, dim=1, index=starts_reshaped_excluded)
>>> ends_sums_included = torch.gather(hidden_states_cumsum, dim=1, index=ends_reshaped_included)
```

For very first segment with start id = 0 we need to set cumsum to 0 as we need cumsum of excluded ids, thus excluded id for 0 is -1, which cumsum is 0:

```
>>> starts_sums_excluded[:, 0][starts_reshaped[:, 0] == 0] = 0.0
>>> hidden_states_sum = ends_sums_included - starts_sums_excluded
>>> segment_lengths = ends_reshaped - starts_reshaped
```

-1 = any number, as hidden_states_sum is already 0 in needed places, thus further division will give us 0:

```
>>> segment_lengths[segment_lengths == 0] = -1
```

Results:

```
>>> hidden_states
tensor([[[ 0,  1],
         [ 2,  3],
         [ 4,  5],
         [ 6,  7],
         [ 8,  9]],

        [[10, 11],
         [12, 13],
         [14, 15],
         [16, 17],
         [18, 19]],

        [[20, 21],
         [22, 23],
         [24, 25],
         [26, 27],
         [28, 29]],

        [[30, 31],
         [32, 33],
         [34, 35],
         [36, 37],
         [38, 39]]])
>>> hidden_states_sum
tensor([[[ 2,  4],
         [14, 16],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[42, 45],
         [ 0,  0],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[46, 48],
         [54, 56],
         [ 0,  0]],

        [[30, 31],
         [66, 68],
         [74, 76]]])
>>> hidden_states_sum / segment_lengths
tensor([[[ 1.,  2.],
         [ 7.,  8.],
         [-0., -0.]],

        [[14., 15.],
         [-0., -0.],
         [-0., -0.]],

        [[23., 24.],
         [27., 28.],
         [-0., -0.]],

        [[30., 31.],
         [33., 34.],
         [37., 38.]]])
```

Finally, you can see that for padding elements I got zero embeddings. You can exclude them as you want and reshape the result tensor for your needs.